# Add items to one array after each item on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Basically I need to add each item from one array after each on from another array. So if these are the two arrays:

```
array1 = [
"item1",
"item2",
"item3",
"item4"
];

array2 = [
"choice1",
"choice2",
"choice3",
"choice4"
];
```

I need to make array1 become this:

```
"item1",
"choice1",
"item2",
"choice2",
"item3",
"choice3",
"item4",
"choice4"
];
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to include what you've tried in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, to get the best help read this guide before posting a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Given that the arrays are the same length you can map over one of them, provide a return value of an array with both values at the index from both arrays, and then flatten with concat for your wanted result.

```
[].concat.apply([], array1.map((i, ind) => [i,array2[ind]]));
```

```js
let a1 = ["item1","item2","item3","item4"], a2 = ["choice1","choice2","choice3","choice4"],
combined_array = [].concat.apply([], a1.map((i, ind) => [i,a2[ind]]));

console.log(combined_array);
```

**OR**

You could similarly use `reduce`. This may be a better option if you would like to keep away from calling `concat` off an Array object:

```
array1.reduce((acc, i, ind) => acc.push(i, array2[ind])&&acc, []);
```

```js
    let a1 = ["item1","item2","item3","item4"], a2 = ["choice1","choice2","choice3","choice4"],
    combined_array = a1.reduce((acc, i, ind) => acc.push(i, a2[ind])&&acc, []);
   

    console.log(combined_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let array3 = [];
for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
  array3.push(array1[i]);
  array3.push(array2[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forEach()` to iterate over the first array. Then push the current item to the result array and use index to take the item from the second array to push as the next item:

```js
var array1 = [
"item1",
"item2",
"item3",
"item4"
];

var array2 = [
"choice1",
"choice2",
"choice3",
"choice4"
];

var res = [];
array1.forEach((i,idx) =>{
  res.push(i);
  res.push(array2[idx]);
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through them and add them to an array using the index to the element of every level after each others :

```js
array1 = [
  "item1",
  "item2",
  "item3",
  "item4"
];

array2 = [
  "choice1",
  "choice2",
  "choice3",
  "choice4"
];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  result.push(array1[i]);
  result.push(array2[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `push()` method here,

```
array1 = [
"item1",
"item2",
"item3",
"item4"
];

array2 = [
"choice1",
"choice2",
"choice3",
"choice4"
];

var FinalArray = [];
for(var index = 0; index < array1.length; index++){
  FinalArray.push(array1[index]);
  FinalArray.push(array2[index]);
}
```