# How to union two arrays in one in chess order

Tags: javascript

how can I combine this:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [4, 5, 6];

// and get this
let result = [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6];
```

Comment: Post the code you have tried that isn't working.

Comment: Please read [ask]. This question is not in an understandable state, not does it show what you have tried before asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add items to one array after each item on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730761)

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [4, 5, 6];

let result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  result.push(array1[i]);
  result.push(array2[i]);
}
console.log(result);
```

or

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [4, 5, 6];
let result = array1.reduce(function(arr, v, i) {
  return arr.concat(v, array2[i]);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is great solution, thank you very much, but there is one problem. If in array2 will be less elements than array1 than last element will be 'undefined'.

Comment: yes.. then in that case you would need to check the length of array2 before trying to get value..